# How to have the autocomplete feature in jupyter notebook like we have in pycharm or visual code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I just want that autocomplete feature like I have in VC studio and pycharm in jupyter notebook, is there any way folks? I saw in some youtube tutorials people completing the code using the tool, any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hinterland functionality that when enabled then auto-complete code works.

For you to access the functionality first install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions as follows:

1. Install the python package

> pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

2. Then install javascript and css files

> jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

More information on how to install can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugAeP.png)

Then re-start the jupyter notebook. Look for a tab named Nbextensions and click on it. Then look for Hinterland and make sure that it is checkd:

[image]

Refresh/Restart jupyter notebook for changes to take place.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to click the "Tab"-Button after typing something (e.g. a Class name followed by a dot). Then you find suggestions that you can insert by using Tab or Enter.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.